# PythonでExcelファイルに特定の行を書き込みしたい

Tags: python, python3

#### やりたいこと

下記のjsonのデータからmessageId・titleを取得しております。
取得後、該当のエクセルにmessageIdを書き出したいです。

Jsonファイル

```
{
  {
  "tokens": [
    "アメリカ"
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "totalCount": 3,
  "recordCount": 3,
  "hasMore": false,
  "isLimited": false,
  "records": [
    {
      "roomId": 11264811,
      "messageId": 2268867581,
      "writerId": 13489121,
      "contentType": "post",
      "text": "アメリカ\n1",
      "createdAt": "2022-05-17T07:22:32.763Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-17T07:22:32.778Z",
      "commentCount": 0,
      "pollId": -1,
      "postId": -1,
      "todoId": -1,
      "from": "web",
      "isThreaded": false,
      "mentions": [],
      "post": {
        "id": 2268867581,
        "title": "アメリカ",
        "body": "1"
      },
      "target": {
        "from": 2268867581,
        "id": 2268867581,
        "contentType": "post",
        "title": "アメリカ\n1",
        "roomId": 11264811,
        "contentTypeId": 2268867581,
        "linkId": 2262266649
      }
    },
    {
      "roomId": 11264811,
      "messageId": 2268868257,
      "writerId": 13489121,
      "contentType": "post",
      "text": "アメリカ\n1",
      "createdAt": "2022-05-17T07:22:40.405Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-17T07:23:06.210Z",
      "commentCount": 0,
      "pollId": -1,
      "postId": -1,
      "todoId": -1,
      "from": "web",
      "isThreaded": false,
      "mentions": [],
      "post": {
        "id": 2268868257,
        "title": "アメリカ",
        "body": "1"
      },
      "target": {
        "from": 2268868257,
        "id": 2268868257,
        "contentType": "post",
        "title": "アメリカ\n1",
        "roomId": 11264811,
        "contentTypeId": 2268868257,
        "linkId": 2262267315
      }
    },
    {
      "roomId": 11264811,
      "messageId": 2268872585,
      "writerId": 13489121,
      "contentType": "post",
      "text": "アメリカ\n1",
      "createdAt": "2022-05-17T07:23:32.130Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-17T07:23:32.157Z",
      "commentCount": 0,
      "pollId": -1,
      "postId": -1,
      "todoId": -1,
      "from": "web",
      "isThreaded": false,
      "mentions": [],
      "post": {
        "id": 2268872585,
        "title": "アメリカ",
        "body": "1"
      },
      "target": {
        "from": 2268872585,
        "id": 2268872585,
        "contentType": "post",
        "title": "アメリカ\n1",
        "roomId": 11264811,
        "contentTypeId": 2268872585,
        "linkId": 2262271578
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

元のエクセル

| no_plate | title | message id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1563 | アメリカ |  |
| 1563 | アメリカ |  |
| 1341 | 日本 | 2262271545 |
| 1456 | イギリス | 2262271589 |
| 1456 | アメリカ | 2262271522 |
| 1565 | アメリカ |  |

##### 期待する結果

Jsonから取得した順番のようにデータを下記のエクセルのようにmessage id
を書き込みしたいです。

```
#タイトル取得
title= [x["post"]["title"] for x in json_load["records"]]
print(title)

#メッセージID取得
messageId= [x["messageId"] for x in json_load["records"]]
print(messageId)

['アメリカ', 'アメリカ', 'アメリカ']
[2268867581, 2268868257, 2268872585]
```

**エクセルのカラムtitleと元のJsonファイルのtitle一致しております。**
titleが重複する時があります。
message idが空白の場合、message idを追記したいです。

| no_plate | title | message id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1563 | アメリカ | 2268867581 |
| 1563 | アメリカ | 2268868257 |
| 1341 | 日本 | 2262271545 |
| 1456 | イギリス | 2262271589 |
| 1456 | アメリカ | 2262271522 |
| 1565 | アメリカ | 2268872585 |

現在、下記のコードでセルを指定して書き出しております。
毎回データが変化するので、セルを指定せずに自動的に該当のmessageIdに入力可能でしょうか。
pandasもしくはopenpyxlで書き込みが詳しい方教えていただけませんでしょうか。

全体コード

```
from email import message
import json
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

json_open = open("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.json", 'r')
json_load = json.load(json_open)

print(json_load)

#messageId取得方法　for分なし
#messageId = json_load["records"][0]["messageId"]
#messageId = json_load["records"][0]["post"]["title"]
#print(messageId)

#タイトル取得
title= [x["post"]["title"] for x in json_load["records"]]
print(title)

#メッセージID取得
messageId= [x["messageId"] for x in json_load["records"]]
print(messageId)

#エクセルファイル
excelfile="C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\country.xlsx"

#エクセル読み込み
df = pd.read_excel(excelfile)
print(df)

# #df.loc['アメリカ':'アメリカ', 'アメリカ'] = [messageId]  
# print(df)

# ワークブックを読み込む
wb = load_workbook(excelfile)

#シート指定 
ws = wb['Sheet1']
#value値をDataFrameに変換
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)

#JSONファイルから取得したタイトルとメッセージIDをエクセルに入力
ws['C2'] = json_load["records"][0]["messageId"]

ws['C3'] = json_load["records"][1]["messageId"]

ws['C6'] = json_load["records"][2]["messageId"]

#エクセル保存
wb.save(excelfile)

#エクセル読み込み
print(df)
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Jsonファイルの2行目(`{`)は余計な行ですので削除しておきましょう。

Comment: jsonから抽出したデータをexcelの中に反映する場所を選択する考え方が明確では無いと思われます。また例は偶々全てアメリカですしmessage idは空欄ですが、これが混ざっていたりexcelよりも多かったり既に代入されていたり、といった場合があるのか？その時どうするのか？といった事も明確になっている必要があるでしょう。そのあたりを考慮・検討して追記してみてください。

Comment: 元のエクセルと JSON のデータがどう紐づくのかが分かりませんでした。作ろうとしているプログラム全体の説明よりも、細かいステップに分解していってどこで躓いているのかを明確にした上で質問を組み立ててみてください。

Comment: みなさん回答ありがとうございます。
失礼しました。`エクセルのカラムtitleと元のJsonファイルのtitle一致しております。`もう少し分かりやすくに質問へ編集しました。

Comment: エクセルの title をキーに messageid を入れるとの事ですが、title が重複している場合の処理が考慮されていないように見えます。

Comment: 取り敢えずexcelの中でtitleが合っていてmessage idの空いている所を上から順番に埋めていく。excelに合うtitleが無ければ何もしない、という緩い仕様で考えて回答しておきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな形で`openpyxl`は不要で`pandas`で出来るでしょう。

該当部分を抜粋します。

```
#エクセル読み込み
df = pd.read_excel(excelfile, dtype=str)
print(df)

for curtitle, curmsgid in zip(title, messageId):
    wdf = df.query('(title == @curtitle) and (`message id` != `message id`)')
    if len(wdf) <= 0: continue
    df.at[wdf.index[0], 'message id'] = curmsgid

df.to_excel(excelfile,index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: 早速回答ありがとうございます。`zip関数`と`query`の勉強になりました。
まだ100%理解していないですが、下記の参考ページで自分でも試してみます。
https://note.nkmk.me/python-zip-usage-for/
https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-query/

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方法でできました。ちなみに現在は空白がある時だけ書き込みしていますが、`messageId`があっても上書きできますでしょうか。下記の方法でコメントアウトしてやってみましたが上手くできませんでした。もしこちらも分かりましたら、教えていただけると嬉しいです。
`# if len(wdf) <= 0: continue
    # df.at[wdf.index[0], 'messageid'] = curmsgid`

Comment: 出来るとは思いますが単純には思いつきません。コメントしたように細かい条件や場合分けの考え方を突き詰めて新規に質問を起こしてもらった方が良いでしょう。良く上手い回答をしてくれる他の人などがスパッと回答してくれるかもしれません。

Comment: かしこまりました。ありがとうございます。